# One fragment cares about screen orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm making an app to follow the single activity rule - there's only one activity in the whole APP lifecycle, the screens are just Fragments.

Apart from one/two fragments, The whole application ONLY support landscape screen orientation. The AndroidManifest.xml is as following:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activity.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Question: How do I lock all my fragments?
I tried by overriding the onConfigurationChanged in the activity, but it never get invoked.

Comment: `android:screenOrientation="portrait` "locks" screen orientation to portrait ... now why/when onConfigurationChanged should be called?

Comment: Well, that's part of the question, is there a way that I can lock all the fragment other than one or two?

Comment: If I understand right, why is android:screenOrientation set to portrait instead of landscape. I thought that is what you want, from your statement "...whole application ONLY support landscape screen".

Comment: Please post the question or problem. Now, there is none. Sample question, "How do I lock all my fragments?". This sentence can come before And I overrided the onConfigurationChanged... I hope you're fine with that. Please review it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right (cause it is not clear) you want to lock the Activity and all your fragments.
Technically you have set the configuration for your whole and only Activity, which should impact your fragments. If that is not so, then I suspect the fragments disabled your settings on it. My only suggestion is to add code in onCreateView() and call setRequestedOrientation()

Code suggestion in the fragments:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
MainActivity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);
...
}
```